# How to make a code branch that does not need `npm install` to work

Tags: npm, npm-install

I have a web app that uses npm to install a big list of dependencies.

I want to make a branch that will...

a) permanently freeze all dependency versions,

b) work when checked out, without having to run `npm install` (i.e. unable to retrieve libraries from the internet), and

c) allow a developer to fix bugs.

It seems like committing `/node_modules` to the repo accomplishes this, but I do not have enough knowledge to know that this is really the correct answer in all situations.

Comment: `package.json` ?

Comment: Please expand that comment. What are you asking exactly? Thanks

Comment: I just wanted your opinion on [package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json). You surely must be using it already. How does it not fit your requirement and why would you opt for not installing dependencies? Perhaps you can edit and share the reasoning in the question itself.

Comment: When the app is checked out from the repo, the user may be unable to get libraries from the internet, so all dependencies need to be in the repo. I assume `package.json` by itself will not suffice, but `/node-modules` needs to be in the repo. But I do not know `npm` enough to say for certain.